# Why Ruby has different quotation marks for exception message and backtrace?

Tags: ruby

I don't understand why Ruby has different quotation marks. Example of code:

```rb
3.0.1 :001 > class A
3.0.1 :002 > end
 => nil
3.0.1 :003 > A.new.foo
(irb):3:in `<main>': undefined method `foo' for #<A:0x00007fb1932cf578> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/vladislavkopylov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.3.5/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/vladislavkopylov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.1/bin/irb:23:in `load'
    from /Users/vladislavkopylov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.1/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
3.0.1 :004 >
```

Looking at

```
`foo'
```

I don't understand why left and right quotation marks are different. Left is "`" and right is "'".

The same situation in the backtrace:

```
`<top (required)>'
`load'
`<main>'
```

Is it a bug or legacy?

Comment: It resembles the ‘ …’ quotation marks. TeX also uses this variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Ruby. This is simply a way of approximating typographically correct quotation marks using the limited set of symbols available in ASCII, and even older character sets before that.

It has been widely used in email, Usenet, text documents, printed documents, and typesetting languages (e.g. TeX) for over 40 years.

Compare the typographically correct version, the version using only the ASCII quotation marks, and the version using the "fake" quotation marks:

- John said: “Welcome to ‘Foocamp’ everybody.”
- John said: "Welcome to 'Foocamp' everybody."
- John said: ``Welcome to `Foocamp' everybody.'' *or* John said: ``Welcome to `Foocamp' everybody."

Remember, when many of our current typographical conventions for plain text files were established, ASCII was not yet in widespread use. Earlier 7 bit character sets often included more mathematical symbols than ASCII does and fewer typographical symbols. (For example, some had arrows, inequality, etc. but no quotation marks at all!) Also, there were 6 bit character sets (i.e. limited to 64 characters) and even some special encodings like DEC RADIX 50, which only included 40 characters.

DEC RADIX 50 is really influential for a lot of things, because Unix and C were invented on DEC platforms. For example, using RADIX 50, you can encode 9 characters in three words, which is the origin of the 6.3 filename convention in DEC operating systems that was carried over in Unix and was still present in POSIX until recently. (Yes, until recently, POSIX only guaranteed filenames of 6 characters, a dot, and another 3 characters, and only from a limited set of characters.) Ever wondered about some of the cryptic names of C standard library header files? It was literally *not possible* for them to be longer than 6 characters!

Also, bitmap printers and displays did not yet exist either, or at least were not in widespread use. So, typography had to be "faked" using whatever characters and features the printer had available – there was no way to draw your own.

Comment: Thank you for your significant answer! 